# Swing positioning issue

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, flicker

I am writing a small game, using `Swing` for `GUI` and I ran into a problem. I'm posting a screenshot, so that you can get a better grasp of the situation.

[image]

At first I only had the board for which I used a `GridLayout`.

However, I needed to add a panel for displaying the scores, so I dropped the `GridLayout` in favour of `GridBagLayout`. I positioned properly the new `JPanel` for the scores and added 2 `JTextArea` in it for displaying the results.

The thing is that each time one of the players will make a move(and hence the board gets redrawn to reflect its new state) the text areas will flicker and be partially covered by the board(see screenshot). Any idea what the issue might be? I have set the preferred size of all the components and tried using `setOpaque` but it was to no avail.

The code of the main layout holder.

```
public class BoardLayout extends JFrame implements ModelObserver {

    /**
     * {@value}
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5834762299789973250L;

    /**
     * {@value}
     */
    private static final int RESULTS_PANEL_HEIGHT = 100;

    private final BoardEventsListener eventsListener;

    private final ResultsLayout resultsLayout;

    private class CellMouseListener implements MouseListener {

        private final int cellIndex;

        public CellMouseListener(final int index) {
            cellIndex = index;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) {
            eventsListener.onCellSelected(cellIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent event) {
            // blank
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(final MouseEvent event) {
            // blank
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent event) {
            // blank
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent event) {
            // blank
        }

    }

    public BoardLayout(final BoardEventsListener listener) throws HeadlessException {
        this(listener, "", null);
    }

    public BoardLayout(GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration) {
        this(null, "", graphicsConfiguration);
    }

    public BoardLayout(final BoardEventsListener listener, String title,
            GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration) {
        super(title, graphicsConfiguration);

        eventsListener = listener;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBoardSize();
        populateCells();
        resultsLayout = attachResultsLayout();

        resultsLayout.setOpaque(true);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private ResultsLayout attachResultsLayout() {
        final ResultsLayout resultsLayout = new ResultsLayout(Game.BOARD_COLUMN_COUNT
                * BoardCellLayout.WIDTH_BOARD_CELL, RESULTS_PANEL_HEIGHT);
        final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        constraints.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 8;
        getContentPane().add(resultsLayout, constraints, 64);
        return resultsLayout;
    }

    private void setBoardSize() {
        final Dimension boardDimension = getBoardDimension();
        setMinimumSize(boardDimension);
        setSize(boardDimension);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private void populateCells() {
        final Container container = getContentPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.BOARD_ROW_COUNT; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.BOARD_COLUMN_COUNT; ++j) {
                final BoardCellLayout currentCell = new BoardCellLayout();
                final int cellIndex = i * Game.BOARD_COLUMN_COUNT + j;
                final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                constraints.gridx = j;
                constraints.gridy = i;
                container.add(currentCell, constraints, cellIndex);
                currentCell.setOpaque(true);
                currentCell.addMouseListener(new CellMouseListener(cellIndex));
            }
        }
    }

    private Dimension getBoardDimension() {
        final Dimension boardDimension = new Dimension(Game.BOARD_COLUMN_COUNT
                * BoardCellLayout.WIDTH_BOARD_CELL, (Game.BOARD_ROW_COUNT + 1)
                * BoardCellLayout.HEIGHT_BOARD_CELL);
        return boardDimension;
    }

    public BoardLayout(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        this(null, title, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(final boolean isVisible) {
        super.setVisible(isVisible);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void onModelChanged(Collection<Cell> changedCells, final int whiteDiscsCount,
            final int blackDiscsCount) {
        for (final Cell cell : changedCells) {
            final BoardCellLayout boardCell = getCellAt(cell.getIndex());
            boardCell.take(cell.getOwner());
        }
        resultsLayout.onResultChanged(whiteDiscsCount, blackDiscsCount);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNextMovesAcquired(Collection<Cell> nextMoves) {
        clearCellHighlight();
        for (final Cell cell : nextMoves) {
            final BoardCellLayout boardCell = getCellAt(cell.getIndex());
            boardCell.highlight();
        }
    }

    private void clearCellHighlight() {
        final Container container = getContentPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < container.getComponentCount() - 1; ++i) {
            final BoardCellLayout boardCellLayout = (BoardCellLayout) container.getComponent(i);
            boardCellLayout.clearHighlight();
        }
    }

    private BoardCellLayout getCellAt(final int index) {
        final Container container = getContentPane();
        return (BoardCellLayout) container.getComponent(index);
    }
}
```

Code of the panel, holding the results:

```
public class ResultsLayout extends JPanel {

    /**
     * {@value}
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8379710427718395507L;

    private final ResultsTextView whiteTextView;

    private final ResultsTextView blackTextView;

    public ResultsLayout(final int width, final int height) {
        super(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        setVisible(true);

        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(width, height);
        setMinimumSize(dimension);
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        setSize(dimension);

        whiteTextView = new ResultsTextView(Player.WHITE);
        blackTextView = new ResultsTextView(Player.BLACK);

        add(whiteTextView, 0);
        add(blackTextView, 1);
    }

    public void onResultChanged(final int whiteDiscsCount, final int blackDiscsCount) {
        whiteTextView.setDiscCount(whiteDiscsCount);
        blackTextView.setDiscCount(blackDiscsCount);
    }

}
```

Code of the JTextArea, holding the result:

```
public class ResultsTextView extends JTextArea {

    /**
     * {@value}
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6354085779793155063L;

    /**
     * {@value}
     */
    public static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#066f02";

    private static final int START_DISCS_NUMBER = 2;

    private final Player player;

    public ResultsTextView(final Player player) {
        super();
        setEditable(false);

        setBackground(Color.decode(BACKGROUND_COLOR));

        this.player = player;
        setText(player.toString() + " result is: " + START_DISCS_NUMBER);

        final Dimension dimension = new Dimension(100, 20);
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        setMinimumSize(dimension);
        setMaximumSize(dimension);
    }

    public void setDiscCount(final int discCount) {
        setText(player.toString() + " result is:" + discCount);
    }

}
```

Comment: Plenty, but without the code you're using, none that are useful to you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I was not using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for updating the GUI and that was causing the flickering. I started using it and it's all fine now :)

Comment: It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a score panel makes me think of an [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) pattern in which both the game board and the score are *views* that listen to the same game *model*. An [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) cited there is also a grid based game that might offer some insight on design and layout. In particular, the `RCStatus` view, in `BorderLayout.NORTH`, and the `RCInfo` view, in `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, each listen to the `RCModel`. The game panel occupies `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

A few notes on the fragments you provided:

- Let your main view extend `JPanel` and add it to a `JFrame` instance.
- Don't try to solve every problem with a single layout.
- Consider `extends MouseAdapter` over `implements MouseListener`.
- Reconsider [`setXxxSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: Agreed, separate your board panel with your bottom panel. Have them be respective panels; board with `GridLayout`, and add them both to the container using `BorderLayout.CENTER` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, setting the preferred size of the bottom panel to `new Dimension(0, preferredHeight);`

Comment: @paranoid-android: Good points; thank you for commenting. The example cited renders the grid directly; as an alternative, this [game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) use s `GridLayout` of buttons.

Comment: Thanks! I started using BorderLayout, although the problem was elsewhere :)